# Best online website for hunting used field recording gear

Tags: field, field-recording

Hello! I´m been trying to find some websites that sell used field recording gear apart from the obvious ebay etc. websites. I came across to to http://www.bblist.co.uk and i was wondering if there´s other similar websites that sell used professional field recording gear? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

bblist is good but you often have to be quick..
Here's a few I trawl through every so often.

http://www.trewaudio.com/consignment/  
http://www.locationsound.com/proaudio/ls/used.html  
http://www.pro-sound.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=PSS&Category_Code=U   
http://jwsoundgroup.net/index.php?/forum/23-want-to-buy-want-to-sell/

All these sites are for production recordists but its the same gear anyway..

Regards,
Grant.

Comment: bugger, sorry about the formatting.


Answer (score 1):

Though more oriented towards music, my favorite is [Tape Op](http://tapeop.com/), specifically the message board section for [selling/buying/trading gear](http://messageboard.tapeop.com/viewforum.php?f=23&sid=3037c966259d37a8ed078c2a018521a1).  In fact, in was in one of the Tape Op forums that I learned of Social Sound Design.  Also, free (or paid) subscriptions available.  Highly recommended and a great cross-pollination of ideas, skills, talent, and approach to sound.

Answer (score 0):

ebay has been good to me.  :)